# How to compile and run cpp file using g++ in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, g++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use a task, but could only find how to compile:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0", 
    "command": "g++",
    "args": ["-Wall", "${file}"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

I'd also like to print input/output to console when the program is running.

Comment: Also see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-compile-c-code

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking, @KungA?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49399490/8011909

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/tasks

At the end there is an example how to setup the task system to use gcc. If you have more than a handful files to compile you might want to think about using a make file and call make instead of gcc directly.