# How to use VSCode to debug C++ application console app?

Tags: c++, debugging, console-application, visual-studio-code

Hi I read this [Question about using VS code to compile C++ console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-compile-c-code) but how to use VSCode to debug C++ application console app?

Comment: Put breakpoints and run it in your debugger - hit F5!

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin I think you talk about Visua Studio - Not about Visual Studio Code, don't you?

Comment: Right, the Visual Studio Code is just code editor. So go ahead and download and use complete IDE - Visual Studio Community Edition. Its absolutely free. So you'll be able to use proper tool for C++.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin No I'm talking about VS Code. if you see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-compile-c-code you can use VS code to compile C/C++ with Makefile

Comment: As already stated: You **can compile** applications from within VSCode. But you **cannot debug** them. You need to take a real IDE like Visual Studio for debugging purpose.

Comment: @am411998 _"you can use VS code to compile C/C++ with Makefile"_ sure, you could have written the code with notepad and compile with a Makefile, that doesn't mean you can debug it using notepad.

Answer (score 4):

VSCode now supports C++ debugging with an optional [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools).

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently debug a C++ application in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: The [VSCode tag wiki info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vscode/info) says different so.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can debug Typescript and Javascript. But you can't debug C++ until there is a plugin to do so.