# Visual Studio Code compile on remote host

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, visual-studio-code, qnx

I have a project on remote host (QNX, g++, makefile if it matters). I'm using [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to edit sources on remote host over ftp.

How could I run make utility with params from local machine on remote host with [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to build this project on remote host?

I have found [this .json script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30269450/6419156) to run make on local machine, but I can't figure out how to execute it on remote.

Comment: look at this https://terrty.net/2017/remote-code-build-in-visual-studio-code/