# Unable to debug c++ code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code

I've just installed Visual Studio Code v1.7.1 to write my c++ code in for my degree. My programming level is pretty basic, but I like what I've seen of  VS Code so far, save for the fact that I've no idea how to debug or build my code.

I've looked at a few questions on the topic, such as: [How do I set up VSCode to compile C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-compile-c-code)
and have tried implementing some of these into the tasks.json file, including the make command and the g++ command, but when I try and execute it I get the error:

> 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

or something similar. When I try running the debugger, it tells me to set up the launch.json file, so I entered the path of my file where it says 'program' as the instructions imply, I get the error

> Unknown Error: 0x800700c1

I'm just looking for the simplest option that will allow me to write and debug code in vs code, in a manner similar to using the full version of visual studio, but without the heavy project filing system or the 10 minute loading times. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the manual pages. Perhaps one of the menu options compiles the code )CTRLF9 as I recall but could be wrong)

Comment: Are you sure you even have a compiler installed? Afaik Visual Studio Code is just an editor.

Comment: Looks like you're missing make. It is typically packaged separately from gcc. What OS and tool chain are you using?

Comment: Yeah that's the thing, I figured I need something like that but I've no idea what or how - I tried searching for an answer but my knowledge was far too limited to come up with a search term like compiler.

Comment: So are you running on Windows or Linux? Have you ever compiled code on your machine before?

Comment: My OS is windows 10, and given that I don't know what a tool chain is my best guess is I'm not using one.

Comment: I've debugged code in visual studio 2015 before, that's about the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: http://www.mingw.org/ is probably the path of least resistance to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

What I deduce from your question and the comments is that you have no actual C++ compiler/buildchain installed. There are multiple compilers available (like minGW, GCC).

However, what Microsoft recommends is the following:

**Installing C/C++ build tools**

*To obtain your set of C/C++ compilers on Windows you can grab the [Visual C++ build tools SKU](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&__hstc=268264337.7cf1d51637df4ad3e4354b8d1e054b1b.1475247184049.1475247184049.1475247184049.1&__hssc=268264337.1.1475247184050&__hsfp=279654701&fixForIE=.exe). By default these tools are installed at ‘C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools’.*

I have not tested, nor ever worked with the Visual C++ compiler, but it's probably the easiest way to get started right away.

Comment: I had the same issue as OP, the solution in this answer solved it. +1