# How to set up VS Code to launch C++ code from Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code

I have installed VS Code in Linux for CMake projects.

I have followed [larsmoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-vscode-to-compile-c-code/39305544#39305544) comment on how to build C++ project with CMake configuration.

I am stuck on how to configure the launch.json in order to run/debug program.

More specific, I would like to know if there is a way to set the configuration in a generic way and avoid to set the "program" with the program name each time I change project:

> "program": "enter program name, for example ${workspaceRoot}/a.out",

Can we use for example the CMake project name or something similar?

> "program": "${workspaceRoot}/build/${PROJECT_NAME}",