# Compiling C++ in VSCode gives me an undefined reference

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, g++

Normally I use VS19 for C++ programming, but I wanted to try if it works on VSCode on my Macbook, so I wrote a real simple program:

main

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "test.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  testfile obj(5);
  cout << "main.cpp" << endl;
  obj.output();
  return 0;
}
```

class header (.hpp)

```cpp
#pragma once
using namespace std;

class testfile
{
private:
  int i;
public:
  testfile(int in) : i(in) {}
  void output();
};
```

class file (.cpp)

```cpp
#include "test.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void testfile::output()
{
  cout << i << endl;
}
```

I know I could write the little output in the header, but I want to try if it works if the code is split up into many different files. I get the following error:

> (PATH)..\Temp\ccITg6NM.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to
>   `testfile::output()' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The same goes for my windows laptop. I ran the exact same code on Visual Studio and it worked perfectly fine. I tried googling the error but tbh, I didn't got anything out of it...

I run VSCode with C/C++ intellisense and the compile & run plugin.

Comment: The `testfile` source file is in the project? In the actual makefile (or other build system used)? How do you build? What are your build-settings? What does you makefile (or other build-system configuration file) do?

Comment: I don't have a makefile yet, i used the plugin to compile the code. I don't know how to make a makefile yet but i guess i should look into it. On my mac i tried with g++ on the terminal and i tried to include all 3 files but i always got an output failure..

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty tricky... I'm not sure but the linker maybe ignore the implementation of `testfile::output()` in `test.cpp` because the header `test.hpp` include implementation of constructor `testfile::testfile(int in)`.

I actually cannot reproduce the problem, try this :

test.hpp

```
#pragma once
using namespace std;

class testfile
{
private:
  int i;
public:
  testfile(int in);
  void output();
};
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

testfile::testfile(int in) : i(in) {}

void testfile::output()
{
  cout << i << endl;
}
```

I think it is better that all implementation are in *.cpp file like above.

---

**EDIT :**

I use g++ for compiling those files(I'm sorry I don't have VScode environment).

**command line(correct) :**
    g++ main.cpp test.cpp -o out

**output :**

```
D:\workspace\test2\test2>out
main.cpp
5
```

**command line(incorrect, test.cpp is missing) :**
    g++ main.cpp -o out

**output :**

```
${User}\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYKJ92L.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `testfile::testfile(int)'
${User}\AppData\Local\Temp\ccYKJ92L.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `testfile::output()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**command line(incorrect, main.cpp is missing) :**
    g++ test.cpp -o out

**output :**

```
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

**EDIT2 :**

I installed VSCode although I use windows, I think I figured out why these type of error occur.

You might use <kbd>F6</kbd> command for build the sources w/ C/C++ Compile Run, but the <kbd>F6</kbd> command is applied only for a file which is currently selected and showed on editor. You select main.cpp then linker cannot find method of `class testfile`, otherwise select test.cpp then linker cannot find entry point(main) of project.

So if you want to build correctly, you must make kind of build script(makefile, json, something).

If you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, you can fild `Tasks: Configure task` tab. Click them and configure your setting(host OS, compiler, ...) It would gives you default `tasks.json` file with minimal form.

I use this json file(Windows, mingw(gcc for windows))

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "command": "g++",
    // compiles and links with debugger information
    "args": ["-g", "-o", "out.exe", "main.cpp", "test.cpp"],
}
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (build using above json), then its output:

```
running command> g++ -g -o out.exe main.cpp test.cpp
```

It builds `out.exe` file successfully.

If you want to debug or run, use <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or Debug tab on the top menu bar, then its output on debug console:

```
main.cpp
5
```

Debug or run step refers to launch.json file like build step refers to tasks.json file.

for reference, **launch.json** :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(Windows)build test",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/out.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Concolusionally it's not problem of source.
For further infomation refer to this post :

[How do I set up Visual Studio Code to compile C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-visual-studio-code-to-compile-c-code)

Comment: Hi, i tried your method but i got stuck with the error: "undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status". I showed it to a prof and he told me to include the testfile.cpp into my main.cpp and it worked. But since its been working for you without including the testfile.cpp into the main, can i link it manually with the makefile?

Comment: You said you tried compiling with g++ and you got same errors, but I highly suspect that the errors you said are seemed to miss one of *.cpp file. Can you share your g++ command line and errors?

Comment: Hi, as i stated, i compile all of my code with a plugin in VSCode, but after i tried your command on my mac terminal it all applied fine and there were no further issues. Thanks for that! The error i get from VSCode are the following: 

`C:\Users\LUCACH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXvErUU.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to testfile::testfile(int)`
   `C:\Users\LUCACH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccXvErUU.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to testfile::output()
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Meanwhile on the mac everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the command line pointers!