# VS Code extension "Code Runner" does not include <math.h> on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

When trying to compile C code that includes math funcions like sqrt or pow terminal displays this error: [image: Error Code in Terminal]

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
int x1, y1, x2, y2, dx, dy;
float c;

printf("\nUpisite koordinate tacke A(x1 i y1): ");
scanf("%d%d", &x1, &y1);
printf("\nUpisite koordinate tacke B(x2 i y2): ");
scanf("%d%d", &x2, &y2);

dx = x2 - x1;
dy = y2 - y1;
c = sqrt((dx*dx) + (dy*dy));

printf("\nDve tace su udaljene %2.f", c);

return;
}
```

My classmate suggested that is is an error with linux and that I should add -lm at the end of terminal but I am trying to make this work in VSCode.

Comment: Did you review [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-visual-studio-code-to-compile-c-code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, you can edit the `Code-runner: Executor Map` file, and add "-lm" in `"c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt -lm && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"`.

```
{
"workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
"code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
"code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true,
"explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
"code-runner.enableAppInsights": false,
"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"code-runner.customCommand": "-lm",
"code-runner.defaultLanguage": "C",
"clangd.arguments": [
    "-lm"
],
"clangd.checkUpdates": true,
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,

"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "javascript": "node",
    "php": "C:\\php\\php.exe",
    "python": "python",
    "perl": "perl",
    "ruby": "C:\\Ruby23-x64\\bin\\ruby.exe",
    "go": "go run",
    "html": "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"",
    "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
    "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt -lm && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

VS Code **does not automatically look for which header files you are using in your programm and link / include it**.

You can see this through the command which VS Code runner runs i.e.

```sh
 cd {folder where the program is }
g++ {program.cpp}  
./{execute the binary}
```

you can see on the compilation stage that no extra libraries are linked or headers are included. You have to do that  by yourself.

i.e. for your program

> gcc z14.c -o z14 -lm

I also suggest learning a build automation tool like `CMake` which will make the task of compiling and linking very fluent.