# How can I build and run cppfront program with g++-12 within VS Code on Linux?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cppfront

I am able to use Linux command line to build a cppfront hello world program with g++-12. I have installed VS Code with 'cpp2 (cppfront) Syntax Highlighting v0.0.2' & 'C/C++ Extension Pack v1.3.0' extensions.

I'm looking to build and run this example and other programs within VS Code on Linux. How can I build and run cppfront programs with g++-12 (which is not the default installed version of g++) within VS Code?

Input for `hw.cpp2` program build:

```
3rd/
    cppfront/
        include/
            cpp2util.h
inc/
src/
    hw.cpp2
        main: () = std::cout << "Hello, world\n";
```

Intermediate build results (only needed during build not for deliverable product files).

```
tmp/
    hw.cpp
        #include "cpp2util.h"
        auto main() -> int;
        auto main() -> int { std::cout << "Hello, world\n";  }
```

Exportable build results:

```
exp/
    hw
```

I would expect VS Code to handle new `.cpp2` files in `src/` *w/o having to manually add each one to some configuration file*.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269449/how-do-i-set-up-visual-studio-code-to-compile-c-code

Comment: 'C/C++ Extension Pack v1.3.0' extensions. handles c++ not cppfront.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic build-task + launch config approach that is used for these zero-buildsystem toy-example programs in [the tutorials in the VS Code user docs for C++](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_tutorials).

- This assumes you [build the cppfront executable](https://github.com/hsutter/cppfront#how-do-i-build-cppfront) to the cppfront repo's root directory.

Put the following in the `tasks` property of your .vscode/tasks.json:

```json
{
   "label": "cppfront",
   "type": "process",
   "command": "${workspaceFolder}/3rd/cppfront/cppfront",
   "args": [
     "-o", "${workspaceFolder}/tmp/hw.cpp",
     "${workspaceFolder}/src/hw.cpp2",
   ],
   "presentation": {
      "reveal": "always",
   },
},
{
   "label": "g++-12",
   "dependsOn": ["cppfront"],
   "type": "process",
   "command": "g++-12",
   "args": [
      "-std=c++23", // or whatever greater version you're using
      "-isystem", "${workspaceFolder}/3rd/cppfront/include",
      "-I", "${workspaceFolder}/inc",
      "-o", "${workspaceFolder}/exp/hw",
      "${workspaceFolder}/tmp/hw.cpp",
   ],
   "presentation": {
      "reveal": "always",
   },
},
{
   "label": "build",
   "dependsOn": ["cppfront", "g++-12"],
   "dependsOrder": "sequence",
   "group": "build",
}
```

Put this in the `configurations` property of your .vscode/launch.json:

```json
{
   "name": "hw",
   "type": "cppdbg",
   "request": "launch",
   "program": "${workspaceFolder}/exp/hw",
   "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/tmp/", // up to you what to put here
}
```

Modify those configurations as needed. The tasks.json part just uses plain VS Code features. The launch config's `cppdbg` type relies on that feature from [the VS Code Cpptools extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools).

---

Especially for non-toy projects, You might also be interested in [Alex Reinking](/users/2137996)'s https://github.com/modern-cmake/cppfront.

Unsolicited note: I'm more of a fan of [the Pitchfork Layout](https://api.csswg.org/bikeshed/?force=1&url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vector-of-bool/pitchfork/develop/data/spec.bs).